# Issue with export in excel in laravel , vue js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, export

I want to export my booking data in excel for that i am using laravel as backend and vue as frontend.

The very first thing is i am calling href in my blade file.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" :href="server + '/admin/booking-status-report/excel?method=export'+ '&data=' + JSON.stringify(this.bookings)">Print</a>
```

If i dont use json.stringify , my url shows "http://localhost:8000/admin/booking-status-report/excel?method=export&data=[object%20Object],[object%20Object]" and so-on

By default my this.bookings is having data like this [![enter image description here][1]][1]

If i use json.stringify, my url comes like
http://localhost:8000/admin/booking-status-report/excel?method=export&data=[{%22trip_date%22:%2212/11/2022%22,%22trip_time%22:%2202:30:00%20AM%22 ... so on

Below is my controller code --

```
 public function export(Request $request) 
    {
        $dataParam = $request->query('data');

        if (!empty($dataParam)) {
            // 2. Decode the URL-encoded JSON string into a PHP array
            $data = json_decode(urldecode($dataParam), true);
            return Excel::store(new BookingStatusExport($data), 'booking-status-report.xlsx');
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Data parameter is missing'], 400);
        }
    }
```

and then In bookingstatusexport , $data is being called and view is being opened as below -
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
 private $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    public function view(): View`enter code here`
    {
        return view('excel.booking-status-report', [
            'data' => $this->data
        ]);
    }

But if i try to fetch data in booking-status-report by using table and applying foreach loop --
 @foreach($data as $d)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $d['trip_date'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $d['trip_time'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $d['invoice'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $d['customer_name'] }}</td>
    </tr>  
    @endforeach

It returns answer as 1 or sometimes error "foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given". I have tested api call to function, its correct. Please help where i am doing wrong.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2IyY.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HURqH.png
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Vue component, before sending the request to the backend, check if this.bookings contains data (is not empty or null).
In the Laravel controller, validate the decoded data to ensure it's an array before proceeding with the export.
Implement error handling for cases where the data is empty, null, or not in the expected format.
By adding these checks, you can ensure that you handle empty or invalid data gracefully and export data successfully to Excel.

```
if (this.bookings.length > 0) {
    // Only send the request if bookings is not empty
    // Send the request here
} else {
    // Handle the case where bookings is empty or null
    alert('No data to export.');
}
public function export(Request $request) 
{
    $dataParam = $request->query('data');

    if (!empty($dataParam)) {
        $data = json_decode(urldecode($dataParam), true);

        if (is_array($data)) {
            return Excel::store(new BookingStatusExport($data), 'booking-status-report.xlsx');
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Invalid data format'], 400);
        }
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Data parameter is missing'], 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey!! I suppose you didnt read it properly !! My url is giving me answer without using json.stringify as &data=[object%20Object],[object%20Object] because booking contains some data . and if i dont use json.stringify , it gives as [{%22trip_date%22:%2212/11/2022%22,%22trip_time%22:%2202:30:00%20AM%22 ...and so on !! The only issue is for conversion of data !! Image is also attached for api result of THIS.BOOKINGS !